# How to check input is a valid integer

Tags: c#

I try to tell the user that ,whenever he types in a string instead of an integer, he/she should type in a number.But somehow the code within the if statement never shows up.

```
    private static void Number()
    {
        Console.Write("Type it in a number: ");
        int result = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (float.IsNaN(result))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please type a number!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Hi");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: use `int.TryParse()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private static void Number()
{
    Console.Write("Type it in a number: ");
    int result;
    bool parsedSuccessfully = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result);

    if (parsedSuccessfully == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please type a number!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("Hi");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do by `int.TryParse` for that

```
private static void Number()
    {
        Console.Write("Type it in a number: ");
        int result;
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
        {
             // user input a valid integer
             // result varaible have the input integer
             Console.Write("Hi");
        }
        else
        {
           // user input none integer
           Console.WriteLine("Please type a number!");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you it worked Mostafiz!:)

Comment: Thank you for your answers everyone!:)

Comment: great you are welcome, happy coding :)

Comment: @Ryepower what was the problem in answer ? it is always good to avoid variable if  no necessary, I have show you the most performatic way without assign a variable(extra memory use) than LittleDebugger's answer

Answer (score -1):

Try using [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) method to validate the entered string , you can also use

```
int.TryParse
```

Code :

```
private static void ValidateInput() {

  Console.Write("Type the number: ");
  string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

  int result;
  bool isValidNumber = Int32.TryParse(userInput, out result);

  Console.WriteLine(isValidNumber ? "Hi, You have entered a valid number" : "Entered value is not a vald number, so please type a number!");

  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Venkat:)

Comment: @Ryepower Welcome !

Comment: This code is incorrect and does not parse.

Comment: @NJH Can you please mention the error in the code , So that I can change?

Comment: (isValidNumber)?
            Console.WriteLine("Please type a number!") :
            Console.WriteLine("Hi");

Comment: You are using the ternary expression incorrectly. Additionally, your logic is the wrong way around and would display "Please type a number!" when a valid integer was supplied.

Comment: This is the part that is underlined in visual basic for me

Comment: @NJH I will check , Thank you

Comment: @Ryepower - The working code snipper is updated in the answer. Thanks

Comment: @NJH - Thanks, the answer is updated with working code